# Proving that the point spectrum of $T$ is not empty

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

This problem comes from Rudin's Functional Analysis, Chapter 10. It's the problem 15.

> > Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, $T\in\mathcal{B}(X)$ is compact, and $\|T^n\|\geq 1$ for all $n\geq 1$. Prove that the point spectrum of $T$ is not empty.

I know some useful facts but it's being hard to put them to work together. Here are some of them (always consider $\lambda\neq0$ and $\dim X = \infty$):

**1)** For all bounded sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$, there is a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ such that $(Tx_{x_k})$ converges in $X$.

**2)** If $\lambda$ is in the spcetrum but not in the point spectrum, then  $\ker(T-\lambda I) = \{0\}$ and Im$(T-\lambda I) \neq X$.

**3)** Im$(T-\lambda I)$ is closed in $X$.

**4)** $\sigma(T) = \sigma(T^\ast)$.

**5)** The spectrum is never empty.

**6)** Theorem 10.33 from the same book.
[image: rudin]

$H(\Omega)$ is the space of holomorphic function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and $\tilde{f}(T) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\Gamma f(\zeta)(\zeta I - T)^{-1}\ d\zeta$ comes from symbolic calculus in Banach algebra.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If $\|T^n\| \ge 1$, then $\|T^n\|^{1/n} \ge 1$ for all $n$, which forces the spectral radius $r_{\sigma}(T)=\lim_{n}\|T^n\|^{1/n} \ge 1$. And what do you know about elements of $\sigma(T)\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: @TrialAndError For all $\lambda\in \sigma(T)\backslash \{0\}$, I know that $|\lambda| \leq r_\sigma(T)$. More precisely, $r_\sigma(T)$ is the supremum absolute value of all elements in $\sigma(T)$. Therefore, there is at least one $\lambda$ in the spectrum satisfying $|\lambda|\geq 1$. Am I on the right track? Now I need to connect this observation to the point spectrum.

Comment: You know that the $r_{\sigma}(T) > 0$. Therefore there exists $\lambda \in \sigma(T)\setminus\{0\}$. Any such $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: @TrialAndError Thanks. Could you give a reference to this result?

Comment: Or you are just saying that the spectrum is the point spectrum in the case $T$ is compact? This would be new to me.

Comment: Ok, now I realize that this is the case. I should've known that... Thanks again!

Comment: Ah! It seems Rudin may not cover this. Were you taught that, for a compact operator $K$ on a Banach space, $I+K$ is a Fredholm operator with index $0$? Here's a link : http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~jerdos/OpTh/w6.pdf

Comment: In fact Rudin does cover, but I forgot (partially). It's part b of theorem 4.25. Unfortunately, I never studied Fredholm opertors.